# SD reader shows the folder as empty

Tags: windows, sd-card, camera, sdhc

Today I tried to transfer about 6.5 gigabytes of very valuable footage to my PC from my camera. Plugging in the camera directly is a bad idea - the maximum speed it 4 kb/s, so transferring it that way is no use. Then I tried putting the SDHC card into my SD reader. And here is the problem: Windows says:

> This folder is empty.

I can see the files when I plug it in with the cable and I see them on the camera. I have seen many people having this issue, however I didn't find an actual answer. If my reader didn't support SDHC I am sure it wouldn't even detect my card.

I use windows 10, just in case it is important.

Thanks, John.

Comment: Did you try Linux? If all else fails you can still make a copy of the raw data on the card with the dd command and then use a hex editor to extract the video file.

Comment: Gonna try linux now. Brb.

Comment: The file may be hidden. Look at the explorer settings and make sure hidden files are being shown.

Comment: It is not hidden. I have alredy tried this. I am installing kali on a USB stick right now, to test if linux can see the files.

Comment: I am back! This kind-of worked, however, live linux doesn't see my C drive, nor firefox opens on it. I am gonna try more linux distributions now, and maybe transfer the file via cloud service.

Comment: Try linux mint or ubuntu.

Comment: Once you copied your file you could reformat your sd card under windows. Maybe that will prevent this kind of problem in the future.

Comment: I am installing linux mint on my USB drive now. What I am going to do is: Boot up linux; copy the files to my USB's root, upload them to google drive. Afaik live linux doesn't detect hard disks and only sees itself, the USB stick.

Comment: Live linux ditributions will normally see your hard disks and allow you to write on them. Sometimes you have to mount them explicitly though. e.g. in linux mint you can click on "menu/preferences/disks" to see all your disks and mount them.

Comment: You can try with `attrib` and `dir` command to see hidden files in in windows.

Comment: I am in linux right now! It is seeing the files, browser is working. I can't mount my C drive due to some kind of an error, so I am going with the cloud way. I am copying all my files to cloud, and then I will download them from windows. That is the best I could think of.